# Card Layout showing wrong panel

Tags: java, class, object, methods, cardlayout

One panel is added through method where card layout is. And another is passed to a method through the object. The problem is that the Panel of a card Layout is showing panel "1"  instead of panel "2",like  panel "2" is not even passing to a method. There are no errors....

I  tried to simplify code as much as i could:

First class:

```
     public class Game  extends JFrame {
          private CardLayout cl;
          private JPanel MAIN;
          private JPanel FIRST;

          public Game(){

          FIRST = new JPanel();
          FIRST.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

          cl = new CardLayout();
          MAIN = new JPanel();

          MAIN.setLayout(cl);   

      }
          public void Show(){

            MAIN.add(FIRST, "1");
            cl.show(MAIN, "2");
            add(MAIN);  
      }


          public void addPanel2(JPanel panel){
            MAIN.add(panel, "2");   
      }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class meni {
   private JPanel SECOND;
   Game nova = new Game();

   public meni(){

      SECOND = new JPanel();
      SECOND.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      nova.addPanel2(SECOND);
   }
}
```

Main class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){

      Game ticFrame = new Game();
      meni luk = new meni();

      ticFrame.show();

      ticFrame.setTitle("Hey");
      ticFrame.setSize(600,600);
      ticFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      ticFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      ticFrame.setVisible(true);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding your second JPanel just fine, but you're adding it to the **wrong** Game object. A Game object is currently visible on program start up, and within that second class you create a completely new and unique Game object and add your second JPanel to that, so it makes sense that it won't show in the visualized object.

Solution: Don't create a new Game object in the second class, but instead make sure that the second class has a valid reference to the *visualized* Game object. This can be done through a constructor parameter or a setter method parameter.

Comment: I see it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

nova.addPanel2(SECOND); what do you mean from  this code?? to add panel to frame we have methos such as JPanel.add( your panel object).

Comment: i am passing panel SECOND to method addPanel2 (in first class) which is adding panel SECOND to panel MAIN